# Is it possible to run my development asp.net core server out of a docker container

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, .net-core

When developing node.js projects I will normally use docker compose to bring up an entire stack of docker containers in order to develop on my local host. I mount volumes in and use nodemon to automatically update the running server. This works well. However, it does not seem to work quite the same way with asp.net core.

Is it possible to run a development container for an asp.net core application? I would like to have the server restart when there is a change on the host machine to a file. I know you can do this with the `dotnet watch run` command but I'm yet to see it working inside a running docker container. How can I get this working within a docker compose stack? What docker base image should I be using? Ideally this solution will work from the command line without using visual studio as I'm using Visual Studio code on a mac.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late to the party, but maybe it will help someone.

Here is the sample project setup that will leverage *dotnet watch* command
in a docker container, while source code is being edited on the host system.

As far as I know *dotnet watch* now is a global tool so you can use it with
different versions of .netcore.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for
*dotnet watch* command.

#### Sample project overview

Here is a small example project for demo purposes, made with help of [minimal api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code).
It has one endpoint */freshbread* which returns "Baked bread".

- Folder structure:

  ```
  Bakery
  │   Dockerfile
  └───src
      │───Bakery.csproj
      └───Program.cs
  ```
- Content of *Program.cs*:

  ```cs
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
  var app = builder.Build();
  app.MapGet("/freshbread", () => "Baked bread");
  app.Run("http://*:80");
  ```
- Content of *Bakery.csproj*

  ```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Project>
  ```
- Content of *Dockerfile*:

  ```
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

  WORKDIR /app

  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch"]
  ```

Based on a Microsoft .net core SDK image. It just defines an */app* workdir and launches there *dotnet watch* command.

The "trick" here is to mount into */app* folder your source code from the host machine and let container handle compilation
and server restart, so:

- Build an image (from *Bakery* folder):

  ```bash
  docker build -t dev-container .
  ```
- Run a container:

  ```bash
  docker run \
      --rm \
      --detach \
      --volume /path/to/the/Bakery/src:/app \
      --publish 5000:80
      dev-container
  ```

  Publish port outside, so api will be accessible from the host machine.
- Now, container is watching files in mounted folder and whenever there are chages
  it will perform hot-reload.

#### Demo

Here is a short demo of this setup, note that top and bottom-right splits are host machine terminals and bottom-left split is log of the container.

[image]